# Rails 7 "delete method" and "No route matches [GET]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the below script for deleting the draft posts

```
<%= link_to "Delete", api_post_path(draft), method: :delete, 
                                            remote: true %>
```

**It works properly**, but after updating the rails version to `7.0.3` it's not working anymore.
These are my project information

1. I have the Libraries **collection**

```
# app/controllers/libraries_controller.rb

class LibrariesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def drafts
    @drafts = current_user.posts.recent.drafts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  ...
end
```

2. I have this collection for **deleting the draft post**

```
# app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb

module Api
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    destroy
      @post = current_user.posts.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

3. this is my **routes**

```
# config/routes.rb

namespace :api do
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

4. **View** to show all draft posts list with the link for deleting the draft post

```
<!-- app/views/libraries/drafts.html.erb -->

<div id="library_<%= draft.id %>">
  ...
  <%= link_to "Delete", api_post_path(draft), method: :delete, 
                                              remote: true %>
  ...
</div>
```

```
<!-- app/views/api/posts/destroy.js.erb -->

$('#library_<%= @post.id %>').fadeOut();
```

But now it's not working then I removed `method: :delete` and updated the new script

```
<%= link_to "Delete", api_post_path(draft), data: { 
                                                    turbo_method: "delete", 
                                                    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" 
                                            }, 
                                            remote: true %>
```

It still not working then I updated the script again by removing `remote: true`

```
<%= link_to "Delete", api_post_path(draft), data: { 
                                                    turbo_method: "delete", 
                                                    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" 
                                            } %>
```

After that, I got this error

```
No route matches [GET] "/api/posts/xxx"
```

Please advise how can I fix this issue

Comment: Try the following `<%= link_to "Delete", api_post_path(draft), method: :delete, data: { turbo: false } %>`

Comment: I added that as an answer as it may be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
<%= link_to "Delete", api_post_path(draft), method: :delete, data: { turbo: false } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note if you want to delete something with a link in rails 7:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', api_post_path(draft),
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

This link would send a **real** `DELETE` request.

If your `destroy` action ends with a `redirect_to` (which I doubt is your case), some browsers will redirect to a new location with `DELETE` method (causing errors), so make sure to add `status: :see_other` parameter to `redirect_to`, like the guides [suggest](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article).

Comment: This is what worked for me.

Doc for reference https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality